# Printing not working

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, network, big-sur, printing

I have trouble printing documents. I'm not sure whether the problem comes from macOS or whether it comes from the printer, but I'd like to be able to be assisted to figure out what's not working.

I'm using Big Sur. I have added a (wireless) network printer. When I print a new document, a "processing" window appears, and then disappears when it's finished. The job queue is empty. Printing a document triggers a green light (as in, 'ready', meaning the printer was woken up from its sleep state), which means that the communication is working.

The printer is a M2020 Series.

If I go to general settings - Printers & Scanners - Option & Supplies - show printer page, it opens a web page containing correct printer information. From there, if I print the network configuration, it works.

Why is it that I can't print documents ?

Thx

Comment: A Samsung M2020? Can you "Save as PDF" from the print menu, creating an accurate PDF? Are you using AirPrint, or specific print drivers for your model?

Comment: Yes Samsung M2020. The file I'm trying to print is already a pdf. I'm not that familiar with mac and its protocols, but yes, it seems I'm using airprint, as it says `kind: 'Samsung M2020 Series -airprint` in the settings of the printer

Comment: @benwiggy, so do you have any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Have you tried printing anything else but this one .pdf file? Open TextEdit, type something, print. What happens? Apple Support has a short page about [AirPrint](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/print-wirelessly-mac-airprint-printer-mchl3c1a7aef/mac) which may give you some direction. As always, go to the Samsung site and make sure you download the [latest available drivers](https://www.driversamsung.com/samsung-m2020-download-driver/) from Samsung (HP).

Comment: Yes, multiple apps, multiples files, same effect. For a weird reason, can't print anything except the printer settings.

Comment: I'm really struggling to find ways to 'debug' this and find out what's going on. Nothing happens, and I don't know why... Can @IconDaemon or benwiggy plz heop ?

Comment: TBH - I've never had any success with wireless printing with Epson, HP or Canon printers for the past 10 years. I'd spend about an hour trying to get them to work, then end up connecting the USB cable and moving on.

Comment: You can have a look at /var/log/cups/*. This should give you some information, what the mac thinks about your print job. But I fear it's a problem on the printer side. Have you the possibility to print from another device to test the printer?